# How to represent this xml syntax as an object for node soap

Tags: node.js, xml, web-services, soap, node-soap

I am trying to consume a soap web service, it works with soap ui but when I use node soap, it does not. I believe the problem is coming from sending a wrong body. This is the body that is to be sent to the web service and this works on soap ui.

```
<arg0><![CDATA[<C24TRANREQ><PROCESSING_CODE>07</PROCESSING_CODE>
<DR_ACCT_NUM>0711201711</DR_ACCT_NUM><TRAN_CRNCY_CODE>KSD</TRAN_CRNCY_CODE>
</C24TRANREQ> ]]></arg0>
```

In the object for node-soap, I simply send this below as the args object

```
const args = {
    PROCESSING_CODE: 07,
    TRAN_CRNCY_CODE: "KSD",
    DR_ACCT_NUM: 0711201711
}
```

I want to believe my empty response is coming from not including `arg0` and `C24TRANREQ` in my node-soap object. How do I include this?
Also are the numbers to be javascript strings or just numbers?

Comment: did you try this?
`const obj = {
    arg0: {
        PROCESSING_CODE: 07,
        TRAN_CRNCY_CODE: "KSD",
        DR_ACCT_NUM: 0711201711
    }
}`

Comment: Problem is the missing CDATA

Comment: afaik, CDATA is no need. look like you're missing `C24TRANREQ`. or you can try with `xmlbuilder`, make you cdata first and consider as string

Comment: https://github.com/vpulim/node-soap#overriding-the-xml-key i think this one can help you

Comment: yes, overriding the xml key solved it